# Proving commutativity in an operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

In *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles C. Pinter, there's an example where we're told[1] that $*$ is an operation on $\mathbb{R}$, and we're given the following equation and asked to find out if $*$ is commutative or not:

$x*y=x+y+1$

The proof provided in this example that the operation is commutative is

> $y*x=y+x+1=x+y+1$
>
> $(Thus,\ *\ is\ commuatative)$

But why does it follow that you can just reverse $x$ and $y$ on both sides? I thought that an operation was to be understood as a function that assigns a rule to the ordered pair of elements. So if you swap the order, and you don't know that it's commutative, then the new ordered pair might map to *anything*? Have I completely misunderstood this?

[1] http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf (see Ch. 2 exercises pages 27-28)

**EDIT**: my mistake was explained to me in the comments by @panoulis. The problem was that I'm accustomed to thinking of a variable as having a concrete value for the duration of a given example or discussion. But here, the rule is that $x*y=(something)$ **for all** values of $x$ and $y$ in the real numbers. This was a subtle point for me because I'm not used to reading proofs yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your definition $x*y=x+y+1$ where $+$ is the standard addition, i.e you know that $x+y=y+x$. Therefore strictly:

$x*y=x+y+1=(x+y)+1=(y+x)+1=y+x+1=y*x$

Comment: But where do you get the last step from? Put another way: why couldn't the operation * be defined such that

x * y = x + y + 1, and y * x = sqrt(42) ?

Comment: It is an operator. Don't think of $x,y$ as fixed elements. For all $x,y$ $x*y=x+y+1$. For example $2*3=2+3+1=6$, or $2*1=2+1+1=4$.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks. Thinking of them as fixed elements is exactly what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the order of $x$ and $y$ in the expression $y+x+1$ because the operation between them in that expression is the addition of real numbers, which is a commutative operation.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that question badly, so I've edited. I didn't mean to question reversing x + y, what I meant was why does it follow that I can reverse them on both sides?